# Backbone.js: Cannot read property 'wait' of undefiend

Tags: backbone.js

I'm stuck on a problem with Backbone.js.

I'm using [siuying's memorySync plugin](https://github.com/siuying/Backbone.memorySync) to take advantage of models, collections, and their associated methods, but without actually syncing them to a server.

This code:

```
n0 = karass.nodes.create();
n1 = karass.nodes.create();
Backbone.memorySync('update', karass.nodes, {});
```

gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'wait' of undefined backbone.js:466
_.extend.save.options.success backbone.js:466 
Backbone.memorySync backbone.memory.js:78 
Backbone.sync backbone.localStorage.js:188
_.extend.sync backbone.js:276
_.extend.save backbone.js:476
_.extend.create backbone.js:847 (anonymous function) test.js:21
```

where 
`nodes` is a Backbone.Collection of Nodes, which are mere Backbone.Models (with two functions, but commenting them out gives me the same error). So effectively an empty model. Here is the code for nodes:

```
nodes = new (Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Node,

    store: new MemoryStore('nodes'),

}))();
```

As you can see from the stack trace, I'm also using 
I know that the memorySync is a year old, and I'm using Backbone.js 0.9.10, so maybe you know what I can do to fix the memorySync plugin.

What's confusing me the most is that localStorage shows up in the stacktrace, even though I use a MemoryStore in the nodes collection.

**Edit:** Oh, I also redefined `Backbone.getSyncMethod` to:

```
Backbone.getSyncMethod = function(model) {
  if(model.localStorage || (model.collection && model.collection.localStorage)) {
    return Backbone.localSync;
  }

  if(model.store || (model.collection && model.collection.store)){
    return Backbone.memorySync;
  }

  return Backbone.ajaxSync;
};
```

after including Backbone, localStorage, and memorySync.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source for memorySync (line 78):

https://github.com/siuying/Backbone.memorySync/blob/master/backbone.memory.js#L78

It appears it is trying to call a success function, even if one is not defined.

As a workaround you could try passing an empty success function:

```
Backbone.memorySync('update', karass.nodes, { success: function () {} });
```

For longer term use, you might want to submit a bug report or patch to the memorySync project.

Comment: I added some code from a later localStorage's sync. I'll post again once I know that fixed it. In the meantime, here's a link: https://github.com/lowerkey/Backbone.memorySync